# Getting "No symbol in current context" error with ddd

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

I have been using ddd for years to debug C++ code and have recently been plagued with this error. I have searched and searched and found several "solutions" that don't help - especially getting rid of optimisation - using -O0 or omitting -O altogether. I have deleted my .ddd file. I think I found a work around, but don't like it. I switched from gcc-4.8.0 back to gcc-4.6.3 and do not get the error. The gcc-4.8.0 that I am using was built from source.

So there are two questions here:
(1) What's up with the "No symbol ..." error?
(2) Is there a trick to building gcc from source so that it correctly includes debugging symbols.

Comment: I'm using GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: This question was answered by @JonathanWakely in response to another question. The solution is to compile with  `-g -gdwarf-2`